# How to migrate from selenuim to capybara-webkit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I have written my whole cucumber feature suite using `selenium-webdriver`. 
I want to migrate from selenium-webdriver to capybara-webkit.
I have done all necessary steps like commented out `selenium-webdriver` in Gemfile and added `gem 'capybara-webkit', :git=> 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit.git'` and added this line to my `features/support/env.rb`:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

still I am getting this error message.

```
Capybara's selenium driver is unable to load `selenium-webdriver`,
please install the gem and add `gem 'selenium-webdriver'` to your
Gemfile if you are using bundler. (LoadError)
```

Comment: If you have `require 'capybara'` somewhere, e.g. in you `spec_helper.rb`, then that will try to load `selenium-webdriver`.  You'll want to change it to `require 'capybara-webkit'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i resolved this issue by running this command at the root of my application.

```
killall webkit_server
```